# setTimeout is freezing my app in react native

Tags: react-native, settimeout, setinterval

I am using setTimeout function to show 3.. 2.. 1.. Go text before starting my actual functionality

But sometimes the app get freezes at 2 or 1 or GO  and directly jumping to the actual functionality.

my code is as follows:

```
  setInterval(() => {
      _this.setState({
        timer: _this.state.timer - 1
      })
      if (_this.state.timer == 0) {
        _this.setState({ timer: 'GO' })
      }
    }, 1000)
```

So for every second the timer reduces its value when it is 0 its shows GO
But my app is getting freezes 
Can anyone help me in solving this
Thanks

Comment: Are you running on an android emulator?

Comment: No its on real devices only both iOS and android

Comment: Did you set your timer to 3 to start? If it is unset or already 0 it will never reach 0 but only continue infinitely below zero...

Comment: yes I have already set my time to 3 initially

Comment: turn off debugger mode and try and see if the results are the same?

Comment: Once you reached 'GO' you must do clearInterval() I guess . Something like this.intervalId  = setInterval( ...function... if(something) { clearInterval(this.intervalId);})

Comment: @iDev Yes I tried but getting the same issue

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(() => {
      _this.setState({
        timer: _this.state.timer - 1
      })
      if (_this.state.timer == 0) {
        _this.setState({ timer: 'GO' })
      }
    }, 1000)
```

You need to know that `setState` is an `asynchronous function` and sometimes, as at the point of your if statement, the value of timer is might not be changed.

For explanation, consider this:

```
// assuming this.state = { value: 0 };
this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1});
this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1});
this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1});
```

After all the above calls are processed this.state.value will be 1, not 3 like we would expect!

I'll suggest you reframe your function to be:

```
setInterval(() => {
  let prevtime = this.state.timer
  this.setState({
    timer: prevtime - 1
  })
  if (prevtime - 1 == 0) {
    this.setState({ timer: 'GO' })
  }
}, 1000)
```

For more details on setState and async function visit [here](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b)

Comment: \ Hi kept this also but in ios after 2 it is freezed and goign to actual functionality

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this. Since both the setInterval and setState were asynchronous.

```
let timer = this.state.timer
let interval = setInterval( () => {
  if(typeof timer === "number"){
    timer--;
  }
  if(timer === 0){  //once the timer goes 0 then it clears interval
    clearInterval(interval)   //to clear Interval
    this.setState({ timer: "Go"})
  }else{           
    this.setState({ timer: timer})
  }      
}, 1000)
```

Comment: I tried this is working fine in android but it freezoing in iOS device

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you are using `setInterval` not `setTimeout`. you need to clear interval. `clearInterval()`